# Configuring PyDev auto completion in console

Tags: eclipse, pydev

How can I configure PyDev auto-completion behavior for the interactive console?

In my installation, the completion is activated after each character I type. This is VERY irritating, I must press ESC every time.

I can configure it for the editors, but not for the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest version (PyDev 3.3.3) it doesn't do that anymore (previously it used the same settings for the editor in the console).

So, please upgrade :)